# How to show a manageable list of images on a post?

Tags: theme-development, images, gallery

I've created a custom post type called `product`. On my theme's product page, I want to be able to show a basic list of images (`ul>li>a>img`) on a sidebar like this (quickly googled :P):

[image: example]

I want these images to be shown on the post edit screen with a way to add more, delete and ideally, sort them manually.

So far I tried two approaches that I disliked:

- Looping through the post attached images (`get_attached_media( 'image' )`). The problem with this is that adding them is quite complex and counter intuitive. (Add Media > Delete the link on post, plus a complicated way of visualizing the images on each product.
- Using a native Wordpress gallery. The problem with this is that it requires a tag in the Wordpress theme, the location is therefore configurable and it takes a place on the content flow. I know I could replace it with JS but I rather not.

I'm looking for a native way, custom code or free plugin. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to code then you should be using (add_meta_box)[https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box]. Here you should have to input field. 1 for the image upload and 1 for order. And also you should use jQuery for making it repeatable. Or simple use available plugins.

Comment: @Karun Any plugin to recommend? I rather nor reinvent the wheel. I've been searching around but couldn't find any that suits me well.

Comment: You can search the WordPress plugin directory to search for desired plugin. Recommendation is off topic. [help/on-topic]

Comment: I know that. I just wasn't able to find any that's unpaid (I found this one http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/gallery-field/ but's paid).

Comment: @Karun yeah, but the gallery plugin is paid.

Comment: The "core" way to maintain list of images attached to a post isn't very straightforward, however WP provides all the tools you need to build an effective UI. Problem is that it isn't possible to write an answer that explains how to do, because that will be *so much* for an answer. Surely there're plugins out there that can do what you're looking for, but suggesting plugins is out of the scope of this site. In short, IMO this question should be closed either as *off topic* or *too broad*. Being a bounty question it can't be closed, but I'll not be surprised if it will get no (good) answer.

Comment: You could try https://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-attachments/ or similar...

Comment: @gmazzap I see. I find pretty silly that suggesting plugins is out of scope. I think it should be restricted to free plugins though. Plugins are a mayor core feature and using them is no sin. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Mauro Problems are: *1)* this site is named "WordPress **Development**", so question have to regard development of plugins, not suggestions. You can use and suggest a plugin and not knowing any programming language. That's fine, but that's not the topic of the site. *2)* Plugin suggestions, even free, are very likely "shopping list questions" a thing that is off-topic in almost all Stack Overflow network (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)

Comment: @gmazzap Alright. I guess this is not a discussion for this area. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ialocin **answering** with a plugin suggestion is fine, if the answer is not link-only. **request** a plugin is not fine. I know I can suggest plugins, I actually suggested a lot of plugins, but that does not mean that asking for plugin suggestion is on topic. If I had a plugin to suggest for this specific question, I would suggest it, but I have not.

Comment: @gmazzap noted. But why is asking for a plugin not fine? I very often came to this problem: I know I'm not trying to do something too weird (as this case). I know there should be a plugin out there to do what I want, I just can't find it googling, probably because I don't know how to look (there are often "key" words that lead to the plugin that don't come to my mind, english is a second language to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Screenshot of edit screen http://www.sitekick.com/static/img/193593.jpg](http://www.sitekick.com/static/img/193593.jpg)

I am working on something that uses images in a very similar fashion.  As mentioned, you will need to implement custom meta boxes for your 'product' post type to create an image field. I use the [CMB2 framework](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cmb2/) to build out the meta boxes.  It provides several field types, one of which is file_list.

File_list allows you to set multiple images via the native media manager.  You sort by dragging the thumbnails in the desired order; delete with the red minus icon, and add more.(see screenshot)

On the frontend, I use get_post_meta to get the image data.  In my case I build out a slider with the help of wp_prepare_attachment_for_js, but you could obviously use it in a widget or your theme.